# Koin re-injecting an instance after closing

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

I am new with Koin, I am creating an instance of object and giving it a scope with an id of SESSION , so after i close it. i want that an new instance for it be created the very next time it is accessed.

```
val InkModule = module {
   scope("SESSION") { providesInkDevice(get(), get()) }
    }

fun providesInkDevice(application: Application, preferences: PreferenceUtility): InkDevice {
    return InkDeviceFactory.createClient(application, Gson().fromJson(preferences.deviceInfo, InkDeviceInfo::class.java)) }
```

So now when i inject an instance i always create a scope

```
  private val inkDevice: InkDevice by inject()//Lazy injection 

 try {
            scope = getKoin().getScope("SESSION")
        } catch (e: NoScopeFoundException) {
            scope = getKoin().createScope("SESSION")
            Timber.e(e, "Cannot create new scope")
        } 

        inkDevice.connect()//here a new instance is created when we access it first time
```

Now when after some time i want to recreate a new Instance of my Object(inkDevice)
, 
so i decided to do scope.close

```
scope = getKoin().getScope("SESSION")
            inkDevice.dispose()
            preferenceUtility.deviceInfo = ""

            scope = getKoin().createScope("SESSION")
```

but after i close the session, it is not able create a new instance the next time i access it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No.. Couldn't find anything